# Create a new column following complex condition

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

Here is the full explanation of the situation. My code seems to not be very helpful in understanding what I want, so I try to describe it in words:

I had people play auctions for 5 rounds, where they were paired with another participant, and each one of them had certain (random, different each round) "Value". Each of them could place as many bids ("Amount") as they wanted. The time at which the bid was placed was also saved, along with info whether the bid was successful. What I ultimately want to find out, is if the person with the highest value won the auction (= placed the highest successful bid[and was the first one in case of a draw]).

To do that (and also for practice) I first wanted to create a column where I check if there have occurred identical values in groups ("0"). Along the way I figured I could also check if the player had the higher ("1"), or lower ("-1") value of the two. To do that I wanted to loop through the rows, check the conditions, and write the corresponding value into the new column.

Below: old explanation

I am trying to create a new column, which should take values of 1, 0, or -1, if someone in the same round had a lower, same, or higher value in the column "Value". The other questions on here seem to only handle very simple situations (or I don't see the connection, I just started this)
What I try is:

```
dat_A08["ValueIsHigher"] <- NA
for (bid in dat_A08){
  if (bid$Value == max(dat_A08[dat_A08&Round == bid&Round & dat_A08&GroupID == bid&GroupID,]$Value)){
    bid&ValueIsHigher = 0
  } else if (bid$Value < max(dat_A08[dat_A08&Round == bid&Round & dat_A08&GroupID == bid&GroupID,]$Value)) {
    bid&ValueIsHigher = -1
  } else {
    bid&ValueIsHigher = 1
  }
}
```

I pretty much define a new column, and then try to write new values to it, depending on the condition. But I get the error

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

How can I access this value?

The data file looks like this:

```
Mode;Round;Value;Amount;At_time;In_stage;Success;participant_code;GroupID;BidToValue;GebAlsHoechstb
2;5;41;41;264.537.857.723.236;1;1;p10;1;1;
2;5;37;37;264.558.881.688.118;1;1;p4;1;1;
2;5;37;38;265.961.394.166.946;2;1;p4;1;2;
2;5;40;60;2.589.505.194.664;2;1;p11;2;2;
2;5;40;40;252.504.601.478.577;1;1;p11;2;1;
2;5;45;45;257.754.272.294.044;1;1;p3;2;1;
2;5;40;61;266.139.678.239.822;2;1;p11;2;2;
```

The whole script should work like this:

```
dat_A08 = read.csv("csv_A08.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
dat_A08 <- dat_A08[,!(names(dat_A08) %in% c("GebAlsHoechstb"))]

dat_A08$At_time <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub("\\.","",dat_A08$At_time)))

dat_A08["ValueIsHigher"] <- NA
for (bid in dat_A08){
  if (bid$Value == max(dat_A08[dat_A08&Round == bid&Round & dat_A08&GroupID == bid&GroupID,]$Value)){
    bid&ValueIsHigher = 0
  } else if (bid$Value < max(dat_A08[dat_A08&Round == bid&Round & dat_A08&GroupID == bid&GroupID,]$Value)) {
    bid&ValueIsHigher = -1
  } else {
    bid&ValueIsHigher = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example`dput()` and also an example of desired output would be good.

Comment: Do you have a matrix?  Another case is that you could do the subset differently i.e. `data_A08$Value[data_A08&` The `&` is confusing

Comment: bid is iterating through the columns of dat_A08, I think OP wants to iterate through rows. As for the ampersand mess I don't understand it either.

Comment: also someone in some round in principle (and probably most of the time) can have a value lower than someone else and higher than another, so it's not clear how to give these -1 0 +1. in your loop you seem to test if it's a max, then test if it's under the max, then I'm not sure what the 3rd option is supposed to be :)

Comment: Oh, yes, I wanted to iterate through rows, am I iterating through columns? The ampersand mess is to find a player in the same round in the same group. And I take the max() value, because it is the same during the whole round, but I couldn't think of a simpler way to get just one value out of the (maybe) vector that I was getting

Comment: Also, I noticed that I should exclude the player itself, but this is not that important now, as I am not getting any values written in my new column. I would be very glad with the wrong ones for now.

Comment: when you use `in` with a data.frame you iterate through columns. to iterate through rows you could use `for(i in 1:nrow(dat_A08)) { ...}` and use the indice I in the loop, or use the function apply that you may want to lookup

Comment: In your example, participant 1, for round 5, was assigned different values, it changes at each bid ?

Comment: It changes only every round. I think in your output below maybe column names got mixed around? Btw, I am now trying to do it with the `for(i...` tip (which was immensly important, I had no idea it works like this), so this might actually help already :)

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if it's what you want. as I'm not sure I understand the whole question (check the last 3 cols of the result).

If it's what you want I can explain in more depth

```
dat_A08 <- read.table(text ="Mode;Round;Value;Amount;At_time;In_stage;Success;participant_code;GroupID;BidToValue;GebAlsHoechstb
2;5;41;41;264.537.857.723.236;1;1;p10;1;1;
2;5;37;37;264.558.881.688.118;1;1;p4;1;1;
2;5;37;38;265.961.394.166.946;2;1;p4;1;2;
2;5;40;60;2.589.505.194.664;2;1;p11;2;2;
2;5;40;40;252.504.601.478.577;1;1;p11;2;1;
2;5;45;45;257.754.272.294.044;1;1;p3;2;1;
2;5;40;61;266.139.678.239.822;2;1;p11;2;2;",sep=";",header=TRUE)

max_values <- setNames(aggregate(Value ~ Round,dat_A08,max)   ,c("Round","max_value"))
min_values <- setNames(aggregate(Value ~ Round,dat_A08,min)   ,c("Round","min_value"))
n_values   <- as.data.frame(table(dat_A08[,c("Value","Round")]))
dat_A08b <- merge(dat_A08 ,min_values)
dat_A08b <- merge(dat_A08b,max_values)
dat_A08b <- merge(dat_A08b,n_values)
dat_A08b$is_max   <- dat_A08b$Value == dat_A08b$max_value
dat_A08b$is_min   <- dat_A08b$Value == dat_A08b$min_value
dat_A08b$somebody_has_same_value <- dat_A08b$Freq > 1

# Round Value Mode Amount             At_time In_stage Success participant_code GroupID BidToValue GebAlsHoechstb min_value max_value Freq is_max is_min
# 1     5    37    2     37 264.558.881.688.118        1       1               p4       1          1             NA        37        45    2  FALSE   TRUE
# 2     5    37    2     38 265.961.394.166.946        2       1               p4       1          2             NA        37        45    2  FALSE   TRUE
# 3     5    40    2     60   2.589.505.194.664        2       1              p11       2          2             NA        37        45    3  FALSE  FALSE
# 4     5    40    2     40 252.504.601.478.577        1       1              p11       2          1             NA        37        45    3  FALSE  FALSE
# 5     5    40    2     61 266.139.678.239.822        2       1              p11       2          2             NA        37        45    3  FALSE  FALSE
# 6     5    41    2     41 264.537.857.723.236        1       1              p10       1          1             NA        37        45    1  FALSE  FALSE
# 7     5    45    2     45 257.754.272.294.044        1       1               p3       2          1             NA        37        45    1   TRUE  FALSE
# somebody_has_same_value
# 1                    TRUE
# 2                    TRUE
# 3                    TRUE
# 4                    TRUE
# 5                    TRUE
# 6                   FALSE
# 7                   FALSE
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you did there :/ I will edit my question to make it more clear what I want in the end. Thanks nevertheless!